# Group and divide a date column monthwise in pandas

Tags: pandas

i have a dataframe df:

```
store   date         invoice_count
 A    2018-04-03         2
 A    2018-04-06         5
 A    2018-06-15         5
 B    2018-05-05         2
 B    2018-04-09         5
 C    2018-02-16         6
```

which contains the invoice_counts(no of invoices generated) of stores for given dates.

I am trying to group them such that i get a month-wise invoice_count for every store.

Expected final dataframe in this format:

```
store jan_18  feb_18  mar_18  apr_18  may_18  june_18
  A     0       0       0       7       0        5
  B     0       0       0       5       2        0
  C     0       6       0       0       0        0
```

Is there any way to group dates based on month-wise??

Note: This is a dummy dataframe, the final monthly column names can be in other appropriate format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`DataFrameGroupBy.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.resample.html) and aggregate `sum`, then reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and if necessary add missing columns with `0` by [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html), last change format of datetimes by [`DatetimeIndex.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html):

```
df = (df.set_index('date')
        .groupby('store')
        .resample('m')['invoice_count']
        .sum()
        .unstack(fill_value=0))

df = df.reindex(columns=pd.date_range('2018-01-01', df.columns.max(), freq='m'), fill_value=0)
df.columns = df.columns.strftime('%b_%y')
print (df)
       Jan_18  Feb_18  Mar_18  Apr_18  May_18  Jun_18
store                                                
A           0       0       0       7       0       5
B           0       0       0       5       2       0
C           0       6       0       0       0       0
```

Comment: Very nice and fast.